# Image processing in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, video-processing

I'm beginner in android.
I’m working on a project that I'm supposed to convert smart phone movement into mouse movement via smart phone camera with android. The smart phone moves on a checkboard surface and the movement information is sent to computer by Bluetooth. Should I use image processing techniques to do that? Has anyone have a relative experience or a similar code to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly image processing would be a good way to go to discover movement on a 2d plane.  The checkerboard pattern should make for relatively easy pixel image comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using object detection in [simple way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/498193/Mouse-Control-via-Webcam).

But for your method you will need to implement optical flow analysis algorithm.
Optical mice internally uses the similar technique called Digital image correlation, it captures the video frames contentiously and compares consecutive frames to detect the motion.

You should read about optical flow detection techniques on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow#Methods_for_determination).
& this [slide](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf)